# Windows XP Insists Upon Reconnecting to Network Drive on Startup (Stop It)

Tags: windows, networking, startup, mappeddrive

I once mapped a network drive and accidentally checked Reconnect at logon. Now, no matter what I do, Windows insists upon connecting to that drive at startup. Here's what I've tried in order to stop it, with a liberal sprinkling of restarts in between steps:

- NET USE /PERSISTENT:NO
- NET USE S: /DELETE
- Mapping a new drive to S: after persistence was turned off.
- Deleting everything that matched the share's path (\\test\example) from the registry.
- Disconnecting S:, then mapping a different drive to it (\\test\example2) with Reconnect at logon set. After a reboot, \\test\example2 was mapped. Then after running NET USE S: /D and NET USE /P:NO, rebooting again. Magically \\test\example (the original one) had remapped itself!
- Checking All Users' (and my) Start Menu's Startup directory and local Logon Scripts (nothing in any of them).

At this point, I'm completely baffled. I can think of no other places where such a thing would be stored and no reason why the normal approach fails. Especially no reason for it to be able to reconnect to a different network drive on startup when set to, then revert to the original one when the new one is unmapped. But it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the machine a member of a domain?  Could there be something in the domain's login scripts or GPO that is mapping the drive?

Comment: It is part of a domain, but I don't think they're part of the logon scripts. I'll do a little more digging, but I don't recall this drive existing until after I mapped it.

Comment: Wow. After asking the right people within the company, it is part of the domain's policy. I guess my memory was playing tricks on me. So thanks!

Comment: Fun fact: After associating .vbs files with Eclipse instead of Visual Basic, I've inadvertently blocked the script. Now it just opens up in an editor instead of running, and the network drive is no longer mapped. So if you really -really- want to avoid mapping a network drive, this might be an option to block the logon script. Although I'll probably re-enable it, since that script is there for a reason.